# gcc target for AVX2 disabling SSE instruction set

Tags: c, gcc, avx2

We have a translation unit we want to compile with AVX2 (only that one):
It's telling GCC upfront, first line in the file:

```
#pragma GCC target "arch=core-avx2,tune=core-avx2"
```

This used to work with GCC 4.8 and 4.9 but from 6 onward (tried 7 and 8 too) we get this warning (that we treat as an error):

```
error: SSE instruction set disabled, using 387 arithmetics
```

On the first function returning a float. I have tried to enable back SSE 4.2 (and avx and avx2) like so

```
#pragma GCC target "sse4.2,arch=core-avx2,tune=core-avx2"
```

But that is not enough, the error persists.

EDIT:

Relevant compiler flags, we target AVX for most stuff:

```
-mfpmath=sse,387 -march=corei7-avx -mtune=corei7-avx
```

EDIT2: minimal sample:

```
#pragma GCC target "arch=core-avx2,tune=core-avx2"

#include <immintrin.h>
#include <math.h>

static inline float
lg1pf( float x ) {
    return log1pf(x)*1.44269504088896338700465f;
}

int main()
{
  log1pf(2.0f);
}
```

Compiled that way:

```
gcc -o test test.c -O2 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -mfpmath=sse,387 -march=corei7-avx -mtune=corei7-avx

In file included from /home/xxx/gcc-7.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.0/include/immintrin.h:45:0,
                 from test.c:3:
/home/xxx/gcc-7.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.0/include/avx512fintrin.h: In function ‘_mm_add_round_sd’:
/home/xxx/gcc-7.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.0/include/avx512fintrin.h:1412:1: error: SSE register return with SSE disabled
 {
 ^
```

GCC details (I don't have the flags that were used to compile it though)
    gcc --version
    gcc (GCC) 7.1.0
    Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

**Potential solution**

```
#pragma GCC target "avx2"
```

Worked for me without other changes to the code.
Applying the attribute to individual functions did not work either:

Related problem:

```
__attribute__((__target__("arch=broadwell")))  // does not compile
__m256 use_avx(__m256 a) { return _mm256_add_ps(a,a); }

__attribute__((__target__("avx2,arch=broadwell"))) // does not compile
__m256 use_avx(__m256 a) { return _mm256_add_ps(a,a); }

__attribute__((__target__("avx2"))) // compiles
__m256 use_avx(__m256 a) { return _mm256_add_ps(a,a); }
```

Comment: Can you show the entire GCC command line? Really, you should produce a [MCVE]. Is there any chance `-mno-mmx -mno-sse` snuck in there?

Comment: It is always a bit though to extract ... Fortunately here it is actually pretty easy to reproduce in a smaller context.

Comment: Have you tried using `-march=haswell` instead of the weird / nebulous `corei7-avx`?  (And BTW, `-march` implies `-mtune`, you only need a separate `-mtune` if you want to set it *differently*.  e.g. `-march=sandybridge -mtune=haswell`)

Comment: I did try haswell and other architecture names. I'll amend the makefiles as per the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug.  `#pragma GCC target` before `#include <immintrin.h>` breaks the header somehow, IDK why.  Even if AVX2 was enabled on the command line with `-march=haswell`, a #pragma seems to break inlining of any intrinsics defined after that.

You can use `#pragma` *after* the header, but then using instrinsics that weren't enabled on the command line fails.

Even a more modern target name like `#pragma GCC target "arch=haswell"` causes the error, so it's not that the old nebulous target names like `corei7-avx` are broken in general.  They still work on the command line.  If you want to enable something for a whole file, the standard way is to use compiler options and *not* pragmas.

GCC does claim to support target options on a per-function basis with pragmas or `__attribute__`, though.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html.

---

This is as far as I've gotten playing around with this ([Godbolt compiler explorer with gcc8.1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'+//+breaks+gcc+when+before+immintrin.h%0A+//+%23pragma+GCC+target+%22arch%3Dhaswell%22%0A%0A%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0A//%23pragma+GCC+target+%22arch%3Dcore-avx2,tune%3Dcore-avx2%22%0A%23pragma+GCC+target+%22arch%3Dhaswell%22%0A%0A//static+inline+%0Afloat%0Alg1pf(+float+x+)+%7B%0A++++return+log1pf(x)*1.44269504088896338700465f%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+can+accept+/+return+wide+vectors%0A__m128+nop(__m128+a)+%7B+return+a%3B+%7D%0A__m256+require_avx(__m256+a)+%7B+return+a%3B+%7D%0A//+but+error+on+using+intrinsics+if+%23include+happened+without+target+options%0A//__m256+use_avx(__m256+a)+%7B+return+_mm256_add_ps(a,a)%3B+%7D%0A%0A//+this+works,+though,+because+AVX+is+enabled+at+this+point%0A//+presumably+so+would++__builtin_ia32_whatever%0A//+Without+%60arch%3Dhaswell%60,+this+breaks,+so+we+know+the+pragma+%22worked%22%0A__m256+use_native_vec(__m256+a)+%7B+return+a%2Ba%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++log1pf(2.0f)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:41.00652376514447,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O2+-Wall+-Werror+-pedantic+-std%3Dc99+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:35.291244894334945,l:'4',m:73.91304347826086,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.1',t:'0')),l:'4',m:26.086956521739136,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:34.4750905423101,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dskylake-avx512',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:24.51838569254545,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)).  Clang is unaffected because it ignores `#pragma GCC target`.  (So that means that `#pragma` is not very portable; you probably want your code work with any GNU C compiler, not just gcc itself.)

```
 // breaks gcc when before immintrin.h
 // #pragma GCC target "arch=haswell"

#include <immintrin.h>
#include <math.h>

//#pragma GCC target "arch=core-avx2,tune=core-avx2"
#pragma GCC target "arch=haswell"

//static inline 
float
lg1pf( float x ) {
    return log1pf(x)*1.44269504088896338700465f;
}

// can accept / return wide vectors
__m128 nop(__m128 a) { return a; }
__m256 require_avx(__m256 a) { return a; }
// but error on using intrinsics if #include happened without target options
//__m256 use_avx(__m256 a) { return _mm256_add_ps(a,a); }

// this works, though, because AVX is enabled at this point
// presumably so would  __builtin_ia32_whatever
// Without `arch=haswell`, this breaks, so we know the pragma "worked"
__m256 use_native_vec(__m256 a) { return a+a; }
```

Comment: I am very much aware that `the standard way is to use compiler options and not pragmas`, though I need to understand what is happening before I change anything.

Comment: This does solve the simple use case above, unfortunately it is not good enough for the larger codebase. I am trying to see if I can make a second one.

Comment: @J.N.: The point of this answer is to show what the bug affects and what it doesn't.  I'm not saying "command line options are good enough for everyone", although if you break up your files and your build system can handle it, command line options should actually be able to get all your code-gen done (especially if you use link-time optimization, but functions with different target options can't inline into each other.)

Comment: I did not succeed in making a small sample reproducing the subsequent problem, though switching to "avx2" works.