# How do I efficiently compute reflections and rotations that map the unit cube onto itself?

Tags: c++, sse, affinetransform, isomorphism

For a sparse voxel octree renderer based on octrees, I want to be able to rotate and mirror individual nodes of the octree. Though it is not really an octree, due to nodes being shared and being allowed to contain themselves as a subtree. Otherwise I could simply apply the transformation to the octree itself.

Without loss of generality, assume the cube is a unit cube with one corner at the origin, i.e. (0,0,0), and the opposite corner at (1,1,1). I've encoded the corners of the cube as a 3-bit integer. So 0 (=0b000) represents the corner at the origin, 1 (=0b001) represents the corner at (0,0,1) and 7 (=0b111) represents the corner at (1,1,1). The only allowed rotations and reflections are around the center of the cube (½,½,½) and such that the corners will end up at integer coordinates. This means that there are only 48 different possible transformations. (The first corner can be mapped to 8 possible positions, the next corner to 3 the third to 2 and this fixes the position of the remaining corners.)

I've not yet decided how to encode a transformation, though it should be possible to encode it as a single 32-bit integer (or even a 6-bit integer, as there are only 48 possible transformations). The transformation can then be applied as function that maps each corner of the cube to its location after the transformation. I.e.

```cpp
int transform(int corner, int transformation) {
  // magic happens here
  return result;
}
```

Furthermore I should also have a function `combine` that combines transformations, such that `transform(corner, combine(a,b))` equals `transform(transform(corner, b), a)`.

As those functions will be called about a billion times a second, they should be fast. Though transform will be called approximately 4 times as often as combine. The algorithm is recursive, so if the transformation encoding uses more than a single 32-bit integer, this will incur additional runtime cost for putting it on the stack.

So far I've figured out that the problem can be decomposed into bit flipping, which can be done with a single xor-operation, and a bit-permutation (which I do not yet know how to do efficiently). Though, an operation that does both simultaneously might be more efficient.

I intend to use this in C++ code, which is already using SSE4.1 intrinsics. Though a solution that does not use intrinsics or only requires SSE3 is preferred. And in the end, the speed is the most important. I'll try to use http://quick-bench.com/ to compare solutions.

(Note: I used the affinetransform tag, as there is no orthogonaltransform tag and I did not want to create it).

Comment: You could just concatenate the 8 new corners and have a 24bit integer.

Comment: Then I could implement transform with a simple bitshift + mask, which is really fast. Though how would I implement the combine function?

Comment: If you have two transformations `a` and `b` such that `a_i` is the image of the `i`-th (were `i` is just the natural number represented by the binary representation of the corner) corner, you can calculate their combination `c` by setting `c_i = b_{|a_i|}`, where `|a_i|` is the natural number represented by the binary string `a_i`.

Comment: There's a nice encoding with 6 bits: first decompose a symmetry into how it acts on the coordinate planes (x,y,z) (six possibilities) plus where it sends the corner (1,1,1). Decompose the permutation of (x,y,z) as a sign bit depending on whether the shifted indices appear in the right cyclic order, and then two bits to describe where x goes. (A similar trick works out beautifully for the symmetries of a square... I'm not sure how one deals with a permutation of three elements efficiently - maybe just use a table lookup?)

Answer (score 0):

You can store a transformation as an array of 8 bytes that encodes the permutation of the cubes' corners. The `transform` method would be as simple as an array lookup. Combining two of those transformations could be done in a loop, but this would be rather slow. However, it turns out that SSSE3 has an intrinsic that does this in a single instruction: [`_mm_shuffle_pi8`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_shuffle_pi8).

The necessary methods can thus be implemented as follows:

```
#include <tmmintrin.h>

int transform(int corner, __m64 transformation) {
    uint8_t array[8];
    memcpy(array, &transformation, 8); // This call is optimized away by the compiler.
    return array[corner];
}

__m64 combine(T a, T b) {
    return _mm_shuffle_pi8(b, a);
}
```

From my benchmark results I get that calling transform four times and combine once, costs about 2ns CPU time. This is still a bit slow, but with enough cores it might be feasible.

---

I've also implemented some different methods for comparison:

- Pack the permutation as nibble's (4-bit integers) in an int32 and use a loop to compute the result of `combine`. While using half as much memory, it is about 3-5x slower.
- Work on the 6-bit encoding proposed by Milo Brandt directly. However, I failed to get this implemented correctly.
- Limit the allowed transformations to only a combination of axis aligned reflections. These can be computed quickly using bit-wise XOR. This is about 30-50% faster.

I've created a [quick-bench page](http://quick-bench.com/Dnapv8pUSLyz9U4gGxJ0q9u4Qos), though it does not support using SSSE3 instructions, so I had to disable the methods that use `_mm_shuffle_pi8`. You can still compile and run them locally though.

Comment: `__m64` - normally you don't want to use MMX.  It's just as fast (or faster) to use the low 8 bytes of a `__m128i` vector which can go in an XMM register.  `_mm_storel_epi64` and `_mm_loadl_epi64` are `movq` stores/loads.

Comment: Also, it looks like `transform` is extracting one byte from a vector element and then zero-extending it back into a `__m64` vector.  You could do the same thing with a 64-bit bit-shift and AND to bring one byte to the bottom of a 64-bit integer element with `psrlq xmm,xmm` (`_mm_srl_epi64(v, count*8)`)

Comment: re: your edit: if you want the result as `int`, on x86-64 your best bet might be `__int64 _mm_cvtsi128_si64x(__m128i a)`.  Or `_mm_cvtsi64_m64` if you insist on MMX.  Use `(integer >> (8*corner)) & 0xFF`.  That will be lower latency than a `movq` store/`movzx` reload with an indexed addressing mode, but costs a couple more front-end uops.

Comment: If the only reason QuickBench can't use SSSE3 is because it won't let you pass `-march=skylake`, you could maybe use `#pragma  GCC target("ssse3")` at the top of the file, so you could use SSSE3 intrinsics.
 https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html.  Although according to [gcc target for AVX2 disabling SSE instruction set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51003218) that might not actually work.

Comment: @Peter In my benchmarks using `__m64` is ever so slightly faster than `__m128i`. Though it could be I'm implementing it wrong or the compiler is doing something with optimization. W.r.t. transform, the `__m64` was a typo, that should've been `int`. Using `(integer >> (8*corner)) & 0xFF` seems to incur a heavy performance hit as it is about 40-100% slower. I guess the compiler is really smart about how to optimize moving a single byte.

Comment: I was assuming optimal asm for both ways.  Store-forwarding is efficient, and yeah without BMI2 variable-count shifts cost 3 uops on Intel CPUs.  So for runtime variable `corner`, if you bottleneck on throughput not latency then store/reload is probably better than integer.  Re: using MMX: it might depend on surrounding code.  But recent microarchitectures (like Skylake) have worse throughput for some MMX instructions than the corresponding SSE2 instructions, and mov-elimination doesn't work.  MMX also means you need a somewhat expensive `emms` instruction at the end of the function.

Comment: I tried using a pragma, but then QuickBench returns `error: SSE register return with SSE disabled`.