# GCC: enabling different instruction set extensions in different parts of the code

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64

I work on closed-source (binary distributed) scientific software where performance is extremely important. In many cases there's a valuable performance benefit to enabling AVX and similar extensions, but of course doing so prevents the binary-distributed software from running on older hardware which may not support those instruction sets, which we don't want to do. I also don't want to ship a separate bundle for each CPU feature set. I'm working in C (with GCC) and the target platform is Linux/x86_64.

If I could, I'd like to write code like this:

```
void do_expensive_thing(args) {
    if (cpu_has_avx512()) {
        // inline AVX512 implementation, using SIMD intrinsics
    } else if (cpu_has_avx()) {
        // inline AVX implementation, using SIMD intrinsics
    } else {
        // pure C implementation
    }
}
```

Can this be done? In my experience, intrinsics won't work unless you enable the relevant instruction set (e.g. -mavx512f), but that only works at the translation unit level, so in theory the compiler might emit those instructions in other parts of the code, where I haven't checked for support. So of course I could factor each implementation into it's own translation unit so I can control the flags separately, but then the compiler can't inline them (which may matter in a few cases) and more importantly it's a bit of a headache from a source code organization standpoint.

Comment: Well, if there is such a thing, it would be done in compile time using `#pragma`s

Comment: As in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003218/gcc-target-for-avx2-disabling-sse-instruction-set

Comment: Have different .dll or .so libraries with those functions and dynamically link the one you need.

Comment: Does inlining vs. function call really matter when the function is supposed to do expensive operations? Did you check that the compiler will actually inline the function?

Comment: "I also don't want to ship a separate bundle for each CPU feature set" - how come? This seems like the obvious solution, what are your constraints?

Comment: Usually you want function pointers that you set once at startup.  Link different object files built with different CPU feature-levels.  (Or use `__attribute__((target("avx512bw")))` on some functions, or use GCC's ifunc dispatch mechanism.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing ISA extensions within a function is not possible. One of main reasons is that use of extended (ymm/zmm) registers is either allowed or not for the function as a whole. Consider, for instance, where the `vzeroupper` instruction would need to be placed in your example. Another important reason is that you cannot make your `cpu_has_avx` check a code motion barrier (to e.g. disallow lifting a `vpxor` instruction across the check).

For the same reasons GCC will internally disallow inlining of calls where allowed ISA extensions differ for the caller and the callee.

Hence you have to place variants of your code into separate functions. Placing those functions into separate compilation units grants you better compatibility with Clang and, potentially, a bit shorter compilation times (switching targets within a compilation unit is extremely expensive in GCC). If you need them in the same translation unit anyway, you'll have to use `__attribute__((target("...")))` or `#pragma GCC target "..."`.

Comment: Thanks... Do you know of a way to handle this situation that's just better all around? Some way to, for example, co-opt the runtime linker into loading a different version of the shared object for each ISA?

Comment: You could have a wrapper that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly. There's also the glibc-hwcap mechanism that does that in a limited way (selects between four architecture levels), but it's available only since [glibc 2.33, released in February 2021](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-February/122207.html).